# How to bind ObservableCollection to IList property in XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have IList property to get ItemSource of my DropDown list. How can I bind a ObservabelCollection to IList property in view(XAML)? I tried normal binding but it throws null reference exception.

Note: I can able to bind collection in code behind. I am getting exception only when I try to bind it through Xaml.

I tried with collections of type ObservableCollection, IList and IEnemerable

**IList Property**

```
    public IList ItemsSource
    {
        get { return this.itemsSource; }
        set { this.itemsSource = value; }
    }
```

**Colletion**

```
    public IList<Address> AddressSource
    {
        get { return this.address; }
        set { this.address = value; }
    }
```

**Xaml view**

```
<DataForm Editor="DropDown" ItemsSource="{Binding AddressSource}" Name="Country"/>
```

Comment: can you add the code to your post ?

Comment: Post some code. An ObservableCollection<T> implements indirectly IList<T> then there's no problem to bind an ObservableCollection to a property waiting for an IList. The problem should be otherwhere

Comment: An ObservableCollection is derived from the IList interface, it should work, secondly a null reference exception has nothing to do with this

Comment: I have updated the Code, Anyone please suggest me a solution.

Comment: Can you add enough code to reproduce the problem? Your model? You content page?

Answer (score 0):

It's not because you aren't able to bind but it's not able to find the property . Do check the BindingContext if it is set to appropriate level and postcode would really be helpful

Answer (score 0):

To add **Binding** feature to your Application you can use trick by adding **Loaded** event in constructor of your Xaml Page and inside this event you need add the same code below in **OnLoaded** Event .

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
}

private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.DataContext = this;
}
```